# Can you refresh or requery a main Access form without calling the forms name?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form and within that form, there is a subform where I have a button with an onclick event that runs an update query for a singular record. I would like to refresh the main form on the onclick event in the subform but the issue is that the subform is present in 2 other forms as well, so using `[Forms]![TheFormYouWantUpdated].Refresh` does not work as it causes a "could not find" associated form error loop in the other 2 forms. Is there a way to refresh a main form without calling the form's name?

Comment: Can use `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"` but then that does what it says so probably same issue. Why do you have same subform open on 3 forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `Parent` property of a subform refers to the subform's current main form:

```vb
Me.Parent.Refresh
```